# How should we store our facebook `user_photos` on save for Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want a reliable way of storing photos from the `user_photos` edge from facebook.

What is the most reliable way to keep our photos when we save them so they can be displayed without for example the facebook cdn url changing etc

I store the picture id and have tried using the facebook cdn urls but they go stale after a while, also

```
img src="http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/pic_id_here"
```

Or

```
img src="http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/pic_id_here/picture"
```

Or

```
img src="http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/pic_id_here/picture?type=normal"
```

None of this seems to work.

I cannot find anything at all in facebook about anything really.

Either storing them server side or what is the correct url to link to in markup?

Comment: `/pic_id_here/picture` does work, if you include the user access token as a GET parameter. (Without token, anyone could view any photo by just knowing its id, and that clearly can’t be desired.) So if you only need to show your app user their own photos, that could be an option. If you need to show them to other people as well, then of course it clearly is not; in that case, you would either have to store the actual images on your end, or request “fresh” CDN URLs by making a new request for that particular user’s photos first, using their user access token.

Comment: ok thnx I was confusing myself. I just saw that I can display a profile pic with graph url but not others. So I could query the graph with `http://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/pic_id_here/picture` to get the image and save or does it need a extension do you know? Ah I realize profile pic is public